# Pass properties to React Component in DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a property to a React Component from the DOM. 
The Component renders, without propertie, like this:

```
<script>
 ReactDOM.render(
  BusinessSearch,
  document.getElementById('business-select-root')
 );
</script>
```

This renders without issues, but I want to add a property to the BusinessSearch component. The only way I could find to do is, is by using React.createElement() so this is what I did:

```
<script>
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(BusinessSearch, {personId: 5 }),
        document.getElementById('business-select-root')
    );
  </script>
```

But this gives me the following 
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hu1F.png).

I have seen the exact same thing work in a different application with React v15.6.1. This application has React v16.2.0.

Edit:

The BusinessSearch Component is quite large, so I won't put the full code here. This is how the Component and its constructor are defined

```
import React from "react";
import BusinessSelect from "./BusinessSelect";

export default class BusinessSearch extends React.Component {

constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state  = {
        searchInFocus: false,
        searchInputValue: "",
        selectedId: "",
        businesses: [],
        nameValue: "",
        websiteValue: "https://www.",
        idValue: "",
        editMode: false
    };

}
```

The component is added to the window in app.js:

```
import BusinessSearch from "./components/BusinessSearch";
window.BusinessSearch = <BusinessSearch />;
```

Comment: Please show code of `BusinessSearch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass a prop in to `BusinessSearch`? Just do it normally with JSX:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BusinessSearch personId={5} />,
    document.getElementById('business-select-root')
);
```

Or, without JSX:

```
import BusinessSearch from "./components/BusinessSearch";

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(BusinessSearch, {personId: 5}, null),
    document.getElementById('business-select-root')
);
```

Don't assign the component to `window`, you don't need that.

Comment: The fist doesn't work, since it's not with JSX. I tried the seconde option too, but it gives me the exact same error as specifed in the question.

Comment: @SamCutler, then you have done something wrong with the `BusinessSearch` variable. Check my update above, that's all you need.

Comment: Does import work inside script tags in an html file? I'm getting this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: You should put your javascript inside a .js file and import it into your html. Working with modules like that is only going to give you headaches.

Comment: Not adding the Component to my window and putting the javascript in a .js file fixed it. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<script>
  ReactDOM.render(
    <BusinessSearch personalId={5} />,
    document.getElementById('business-select-root')
 );
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not using JSX here, so I only get: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"